# SQL / PHP not getting any results

Tags: php, sql

I have this script and for some reason I'm getting "No Results".

```
$town_city = $_POST["town_city"];    
$partner_emails = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(email_address SEPARATOR ', ') FROM partners WHERE '$town_city' ='yes'";
$connect->query($partner_emails);
if ($result = $connect->query($partner_emails)) { 
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
    if(!empty($row[0])){
        $partner_emails = $row[0];
    }
    else {
        echo "Error: no results<br>";
        $partner_emails = false;
    }
    // CLOSE YOUR RESULTS
    $result->close();
}
else {
    echo "Error in the connection<br>";
    $partner_emails = false;
}
@mail($partner_emails, $supplier_subject, $supplier_message, $supplier_headers);
```

Comment: have you confirmed ther is data to match the querry?

Comment: `'$town_city'` is a column? If so should be using backticks. Also opens you to sql injections..

Comment: Explain what if `town_city` is your column? I have no idea about that. But if it is than you need to use backticks `\`` around it not single quotes. Quotes are for strings...or are you asking about SQL injections?

Answer (score 1):

you're not getting results as your query is not ok.

```
$partner_emails = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(email_address SEPARATOR ', ') FROM partners WHERE '$town_city' ='yes'";
```

let's say, $town_city = 'ABC';

So your final query will be

```
$partner_emails = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(email_address SEPARATOR ', ') FROM partners WHERE 'ABC' ='yes'";
```

Here, you're messing things up. `'ABC'` can't be a `column` it should be `ABC`

So your query will be like

```
$partner_emails = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(email_address SEPARATOR ', ') FROM partners WHERE $town_city ='yes'";
//$town_city without single quotes around it
```

Comment: @BradHouston: ` this is called tick back so column name should be \`ABC\`